# No sound/dummy output 18.04.4 on new Dell G3 15 3590 with preinstalled ubuntu, Audio device: NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound

After updates from ubuntu 18.04 to 18.04.4 on my brand new Dell G3 15 3590 with preinstalled ubuntu (without windows/dual boot), I only get dummy output and no sound. 
I'm new to linux (only used apple before) and no engineer, so I'm trying to learn fast, how linux ubuntu works and read about many solutions for similar problems, but couldn't find the exact same problem and the right answer yet.

Maybe someone here can help me??

What I found out so far:

While the audio was still working, it was showing in the settings: speaker-sof-skl_hda_card
and Digital Microphone-sof-skl_hda_card

What I found out since it's not working anymore:

Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

Under settings/updates additional drivers:

- NVIDIA Corporation: Unknown
- Device is using the recommended driver:
  NVIDIA Driver Metapackage nvidia-driver-440 is used (proprietary, tested)
- Intel Corporation: Unknown
- This device is not working:
  *don't use this device
- Intel Corporation: Unknown
- This device is using an alternative driver:
- Additional files to enable Intel DMIC audio von oem-fix-audio-intel-dmic are used (open source)

I tried terminal and

```
$ lspci -v

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e10 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90000000-a30fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at a4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at a5310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at a532d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at a532c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 125
    Memory at a5300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at a5322000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Memory at a532b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 4030
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at a531c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at a532a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at a5329000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 7f800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at a5327000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at a5320000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at a5326000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Memory at a5325000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: a5200000-a52fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a335 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: a5100000-a51fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at a5318000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a5000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, sof_pci_dev

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at a5324000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c91 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138
    Memory at a2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at a3000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at a3080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at a5200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a5104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at a5100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2050806), you can try to edit   alsa-base.conf:

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
Add the following line to the end of this file:

`options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`
Reboot